# Use JavaScript to feed data into DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

In `openstreetmap` I'm using `openlayer3` to display some data information about random building. It's a simple interaction, when you click on marker data will be presented.

I'm not good in JavaScript so I had some help, and after a while a set up everything like this, you can check it in this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/6uo6bg3p/) example.

So, I'm using `ol.Feature.html#on` to bind event to markers, and I'm loading data with `info.innerHTML = "<h1>"+data.name+"</h1>"`, and everything is looking like this:

```
/* Create the map */
// setting up coordinates for map to display
var infobox = document.getElementById("info");

var city = ol.proj.transform([-73.920935,40.780229], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');


// setting up openlayer3 view
var view = new ol.View({
    center: city,
    zoom: 13
});


// Create the map
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  renderer: 'canvas',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: view
});


var Data =
  [ { name: "foo",
      address: "Some Random Address 1"
    , longlat: [-73.927870, 40.763633]
    }
  , { name: "foo2",
      address: "Some Random Address 2"
    , longlat: [-73.917356, 40.763958]
    }
  , { name: "foo3",
      address: "Some Random Address 3"
    , longlat: [-73.915530, 40.779665]
    }
  , { name: "foo4",
      address: "Some Random Address 4"
    , longlat: [-73.916045, 40.779372]
    }
  , { name: "foo5",
      address: "Some Random Address 5"
    , longlat: [-73.919682, 40.777365]
    }
  , { name: "foo6",
      address: "Some Random Address 6"
    , longlat: [-73.908980, 40.776013]
    }
  ];


function buildFeature(data) {
  return new ol.Feature(
    { geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(data.longlat))
    , data: data
    }
  );
}


function curryclickonmarker(element) {
  return function (event) {
    return clickOnMarker(element, event);
  }
}

function clickOnMarker(info, event) {
  // This is ugly!
  var marker = event.selected[0];
  var data = marker.G.data;


  // Feed data into DOM
  info.innerHTML = "<h1>"+data.name+"</h1>";
}

var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select();

selectClick.on("select", curryclickonmarker(infobox));
// Setup markers

var features = Data.map(buildFeature);

var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
  tittle: 'City Apratments',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixel',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/data/icon.png',
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(markers);
map.addInteraction(selectClick);
```

I would like to make this look better, it's looking very ugly, so I need someone to explain to me how can I pass multiple data for the marker, because currently I can only see `foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, etc`, I'm using `openlayers3 API` for event's, but can I use pure `javascript` for this so I can pass addres, pictures, description for the specific marked building, because I need to display a loot, I'm just having hard time understanding how to use `javascript` to pass more data?

Comment: I think you have your answer in your code, try this and you will see the address too: info.innerHTML = "<h1>"+data.name+"</h1><p>Address: "+data.address+"</p>"

Comment: Oh, so this is the catch, I can pass ton of data like this, I guess picture want be a problem to, I just need to chain this, right?

Comment: Yes I see it now, been blind for one day, thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, the innerHTML property sets (or returns if called without any arguments) the HTML content of an element (in this case, the div with id='info'). Just remember to add into your var Data any type of info you want to feed so you can call it with data.yourInfo